# matplotlib pops up a window when launched from jupyter

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am extensively using jupyter notebooks and online plots using the `%matplotlib inline` directive. Since version matplotlib's version 3.0 on macOS, I have a new application window appearing for every session opened showing the python rocket launcher icon:

[image: annoying python launcher]

as noted in the comments, this is reported as a [matplotlib bug](http://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12188). this can be annoying as 1) you loose focus on your notebook 2) you get way too many opened windows when running large numbers of visualizations.

This was not happening with previous versions of matplotlib and could not trace any change in the behavior with the latest version. Also I have tweaked my default configuration file but still get the same behavior. To reproduce it, I simply open a notebook and issue `%matplotlib inline` to get the launcher.
Is there any workaround?

Comment: I think this needs a bit more indepth explanation. If you use `%matplotlib inline` you shoudn't get a window opening. But if that happens to you, is there anything more you can provide as to how to reproduce this issue?

Comment: thanks for the comments - trying to include more details. is it clearer? do you get a different behavior?

Comment: May be the same issue as https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12188 actually.